# sql outer join count above rows

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, join

```
table 1
_id    sub_id
  1        32
  2        34
  3        42
  4        44
  5        47
  6        50
```

.

```
table 2
_id    sub_id
  1        34
  2        42
```

## i want result

```
_id    sub_id     count
  1        32         2
  2        34         2
  3        42         1
  4        44         0
  5        47         0
  6        50         0
```

table 2 sub id 34 contains table 1, above 32 -> count+1

table 2 sub id 42 contains table 1, above 32, 34, 42 -> count + 1

```
result 
32, 34 = 2
42 = 1
44, 47, 50 = 0
```

i try outer join, left join etc....
not correct result.

how about this correct result?

plz. help me T.T....

Comment: what u mean about 42 'contains' 32 34 42 ?

Comment: it's mean t2 42 contains t1. t1 42 above 32 34 42

Comment: why result for 32 is 2?

Comment: 32 is <= t2 34,42. count++*2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT _id
    ,sub_id
    ,(
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM table2 t2
        WHERE t2.sub_id >= t1.sub_id
        ) count
FROM table1 t1
```

Comment: You solved this, just want to specify that subquery like this is a performance killer for any RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want :

```
SELECT
    t1._id
    ,t1.sub_id
    ,count(t2._id) as count
FROM
    table1 t1
    left join table2 t2
        on t2.sub_id >= t1.sub_id
GROUP BY
    t1._id
    ,t1.sub_id
```

**Here is the [SQLfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/791ff/6)**

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct a.id, a.sub_id, 
case when c.sub_id is  not null then (select count(*) from table2 b 
where a.sub_id<=b.sub_id)
else 0 end  as counter
from table1 a left join table2 c on c.sub_id>=a.sub_id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d3742/8)